# Have some elements inline & some elements block depending on their adjacent element

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to display list of 'input' and 'textarea' items in a flex box. Each item has width equal to 45% of the flex box.
There is a the difficult problem I need help. 
I need to display 2 items next to each other on the same line if they are same type. Otherwise, display them different lines.


For exmample:
2 'input' next to each other will be display on same lines
[image]

input and textarea next to each other are displayed in newline

[image]

Comment: Please post some of the generated HTML code so we might get a better understanding of the code behind these images

Comment: I dont have a clear code for example but just imagin in side a div, As example in your answer, but there will be random elements with 2 type textarea and input.

Comment: Thats alright, but I really cannot generate a solution for you from imagination. I'm happy to give you a solution, but please if you cannot copy some code, generate some code yourself & update your answer so we can have a more clear technical understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out **css selectors** as they hold the key to what you're asking.

With **css selectors** you can:

- Select all descendants: `using a space`
- Select direct children: `using the > symbol`
- Select an adjacent sibling immediately after the first: `using the + symbol`
- Select an adjacent sibling NOT immediately after the first: `using the ~ symbol`

Read about this in greater detail here: [Understand ‘+’, ‘>’ and ‘~’ symbols in CSS Selector](https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling)

```css
input + input {
  display: inline;
}

 input + input + label {
   display: flex;
 }
 
 label + input {
   display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<input placeholder="input1" />
<input placeholder="input2" />

<label>label1</label>
<input placeholder="input3" />

</div>
```

Comment: This solution will work for fixed elements. I need a solution for randomly elements genrated by Angular.

Comment: @MaiHữuLợi no idea what you mean by that. You have been asked to give a proper example already, so please do so now, by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label for="formGroupExampleInput">EAN *</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Family</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="F&B">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label for="formGroupExampleInpu3">Standing product reference</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput3" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```